# gpg2 command not found even when gpg2 is installed on mac? (trying to install rvm)

Tags: macos, rvm, gnupg

So I installed brew:

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

and then I installed gnupg2 and gnupg like so:

```
brew install gnupg gnupg2
```

I tried to install both again seperately like so:

```
brew install gpg2    
brew install gnupg
```

and it said both are already installed. (wanted to confirm it).

Now, when I try to install RVM like so:

```
gpg2 --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3 7D2BAF1CF37B13E2069D6956105BD0E739499BDB
```

my MAC says

```
-bash: gpg2: command not found
```

Any idea why?

Comment: Maybe try typing just `gpg ...` instead of `gpg2`, it might be symlinked that way.

Comment: I had the same problem and nothing seemed to work, so eventually I did the following: 1) opened /usr/local/bin, 2) looked up the gpg symlink there, 3) duplicated it, 4) renamed the copy "gpg2", and everything started working fine again.

Answer (score 20):

On Mac, installing with brew already gives you gpg2, but it's named as gpg, so you need to create an alias or a symlink. A symlink worked for me.

```
brew install gnupg
```

Get where is gpg located

```
which gpg
```

In my case it was `/usr/local/bin/gpg`

Then create symlink:

```
ln -s /usr/local/bin/gpg /usr/local/bin/gpg2
```

Comment: Just for additional clarity you simply need to copy whatever path `which gpg` output as the `PATH` in: `ln -s PATH/gpg PATH/gpg2`

Answer (score 8):

after

```
brew install gpg2
```

execute

```
gpg --keyserver hkp://pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3 7D2BAF1CF37B13E2069D6956105BD0E739499BDB
```

Comment: interesting, I see 
`gpg: keyserver receive failed: No route to host`

Any explanation as to how your solution works and what else is going on here?

Comment: I've just posted a solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54801274/gpg-keyserver-receive-failed-no-route-to-host-stack-overflow/65858197#65858197

Answer (score 0):

1. `brew install gpg2`
2. `curl -sSL https://rvm.io/mpapis.asc | gpg --import -`
3. `curl -sSL https://rvm.io/pkuczynski.asc | gpg --import -`

This works for me